# Set cookie to hide div when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to display a div (containing terms and conditions) which is shown by default unless a cookie is set to hide it.

I have added my code here to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6ddf/)

Any ideas why my code isn't working?

JavaScript

```
    function TermsAndConditions(){
   days=30;
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   document.cookie = 'TermsAndConditions=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();
}
if ($.cookie("TermsAndConditions") !== Accepted)
{
    $("#terms-and-conditions").hide();
}
```

HTML

```
  <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
    <p>Example Content</p>

  <span class="accept-button"><a href="#" onclick="TermsAndConditions()">Accept</a></span></div

>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot going on with your script.

Mark's got you on the right start: not quoting `Accepted` is not going to make JavaScript happy; string literals have to have quotes.

Secondly, your jsFiddle doesn't link jQuery in.  On the left side of the screen, under "Frameworks & Extensions", make sure you've chosen a version of jQuery.

Thirdly, jQuery doesn't have a built-in `$.cookie` method; there are extensions that provide that, but it's not default jQuery.  And if you were using a jQuery plugin, wouldn't you use that to set the cookie too?  Instead you use native browser extensions to set the cookie.

Fourthly, because of the way jsFiddle works, you can't invoke JavaScript methods from within the HTML without some gymnastics.  Much better to attach the appropriate functionality all within the JavaScript.

So, to get your cookie, you can do this:

```
var cookie = document.cookie.split(';')
    .map(function(x){ return x.trim().split('='); })
    .filter(function(x){ return x[0]==='TermsAndConditions'; })
    .pop();
```

If the cookie exists, it will be a key/value array.  Then you can check to make sure it exists and contains the value you're looking for:

```
if(cookie && cookie[1]==='Accepted') {
    $("#terms-and-conditions").hide();
}
```

Then we'll move the click functionality out of the HTML and into the JavaScript:

```
$('.accept-button a').on('click', function(){
    TermsAndConditions();
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3d928/1/

Note that in your original example, you aren't hiding the `#terms-and-conditions` element when the user clicks the link; all you're doing is setting the cookie.  So it won't be hidden until the user re-loads the page.  If you want to do both, simply hide the element in the click handler as well:

```
$('.accept-button a').on('click', function(){
    TermsAndConditions();                   // set cookie
    $("#terms-and-conditions").hide();      // hide element
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ethan. It might be something I'm doing wrong but none of the jsFiddles seem to work for me. If I click "Accept" the div isn't hidden.

Comment: That's because the click handler doesn't actually hide the element, per your original example.  All you do is set the cookie: the user will have to reload the page to see the result.  It's an easy fix...I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/bochzchan/fkFSZ/

```
function TermsAndConditions(){       
   days=30;
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));    
   document.cookie = 'TermsAndConditions=Accepted; expires=' + myDate.toGMTString();     
}

function CheckCookies(){   
    if ($.cookie("TermsAndConditions") === "Accepted")
    {
        $("#terms-and-conditions").hide();
    } 
}
```

Maybe you forget to include jquery cookie js

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<div id="terms-and-conditions">
    <h1>Terms and Conditions</h1>
    <p>Example Content</p>  
    <span class="accept-button"><a href="#" onclick="TermsAndConditions()">Accept</a></span>    
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="CheckCookies()">Check</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr.Cocococo. It might be something I'm doing wrong but none of the jsFiddles seem to work for me. If I click "Accept" the div isn't hidden.

Comment: After you hit 'Accept', re-load the page.  You don't have anything that hides the content when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to consider:

1. You should have quotes around `Accepted` in the `if` statement.
2. You should use the `===` comparison, not `!==`.