# If you have already closed it, do not show it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a cookie alert in bootstrap 4. I also wrote a javascript code that will close this alert when pressed.

How can I make sure that this window does not appear if someone closed it once?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.close").click(function() {
    $(".alert").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger cookies-notification" role="alert" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="cookies-notification">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
    <p style="font-size: 13px;">Ta strona korzysta z cookies. Korzystając z tej strony zgadzasz się na korzystanie z cookies zgodnie z ustawieniami twojej przeglądarki.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ironically enough, use a cookie.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by *"[...] if someone closed it once"*. Once per user account: maintain state on the server. Once per browser environment: maintain state in a cookie (as long as cookies are not cleared or don't expire). Once per view of the page: maintain state in a variable.

Comment: I do not want the window to appear again after closing.

Comment: You could also use localStorage assuming you're happy to support IE8 and higher: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192296/when-a-user-closes-a-div-hide-that-div-on-all-site-pages